# Find and replace using wildcard character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have very long list in this format:

```
<option value="adf">Option 1</option>
<option value="es3">Option 2</option>
<option value="34f">Option 3</option>
```

With Notpad++, how can I do a find and replace to change it to this format?:

```
<value="1">Option 1</option>
<value="1">Option 2</option>
<value="1">Option 3</option>
```

Comment: Hope it isn't XML or HTML since that would break it.

Comment: No, actually what i need to make is a little different but the example in my questions illustrates the concept.

Comment: Did you really mean to make all the values = 1 or are they suppose to = the number of the option, so in this case they would be 1, 2, 3 respectively?

Comment: @ioSamurai I thought it might have been a mistake too; it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use regex on xml.. Ideally, feed the xml to a parser then regenerate it to the format that you desire.

see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replace should do it if I understand exactly what you want to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: If the option numbe goes to multiple digits, change (\d) to (\d+)

Comment: No need to mess with the name of the option at all (e.g `Option 1`) - you only need to change the opening option tag, i.e replacing `<option value=".*">` with `<value="1">`.

Comment: that is true. I usually do very explicit regexes then genralize them down later.